# How to replace src attribute name with data attribute name

Tags: javascript

I have a html document which uses object tag with src attribute. But I need to replace src(attribute name) with "data" (attribute name).

Is it possible to do so using JavaScript? 
All I referred shows that we can change the attribute values, but I couldnt find any method to replace attribute node name.

Could someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to get the `src` attribute value and set that to the `data` attribute value.

You can use **[`.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeAttribute)** if you want to get rid of the `src` attributes.

Something like this:

```
var att = element.getAttribute("src");
element.setAttribute("data", att);
element.removeAttribute("src");
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TcpMb/)**

If you want to do a bunch of elements, just select them and do a for loop. For example going over all `div`s:

```
var att, i, elie = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (i = 0; i < elie.length; ++i)
{
    att = elie[i].getAttribute("src");
    elie[i].setAttribute("data", att);
    elie[i].removeAttribute("src");        
}
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/24nEu/)**

---

**[.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute)**
**[.removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeAttribute)**
**[.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute)**

Answer (score 0):

When you will be replacing the attribute?

Why dont you write entire thing using innerhtml.

the needed src and all inside div with an id.

just write html inside that div on submit or whenever yu want